# MySQL: fill empty strings with any non-empty value in a group

Tags: sql, join, mariadb, sql-update, sql-null

Here is a table `tests` (simplified):

```
-------------------------
| id | test_name | unit |
-------------------------
| 1  | Voltage   | V    |
| 2  | Current   |      |
| 3  | Frequency | Hz   |
| 4  | Voltage   | v    |
| 5  | Voltage   |      |
| 6  | Voltage   | V    |
| 7  | Current   | A    |
| 8  | Voltage   | V    |
-------------------------
```

I need to fill the empty `unit` fields with any non-empty value in its group (by `test_name`), i.e. the unit for `Voltage` may be `V` or `v` and for `Current` it should be `A`. Is there a way to do it with `update ... join ... group by` or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this query (for MySql 5.7+):

```
SELECT test_name, ANY_VALUE(unit) unit
FROM tests
WHERE unit IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY test_name
```

you get for each `test_name` a non null `unit` (provided there is at least 1 non null `unit` for this `test_name`).

Join it to the table in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
UPDATE tests t1
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT test_name, ANY_VALUE(unit) unit
  FROM tests
  WHERE unit IS NOT NULL
  GROUP BY test_name
) t2 ON t2.test_name = t1.test_name
SET t1.unit = t2.unit
WHERE t1.unit IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0edfa4fbad2065b8868133475366215e).

Instead of `ANY_VALUE()` you can use `MIN()` or `MAX()`.

Comment: Function `ANY_VALUE` doesn't exist (MariaDB 10.3) :(

Comment: @MichaelO. you tagged the question MySql.

Comment: Sorry... in my excuse, it doesn't exist in MySQL 5.6 as well

Comment: @MichaelO. ANY_VALUE() works for MySql 5.7+ As an alternative, as I mention in my answer you can use MIN() or MAX()

Comment: It doesn't work with MIN or MAX: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=4152d8bb5e6f58ab4f014a389af76f64)

Comment: @MichaelO. do you have NULLs in the table or empty strings? They are not the same.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
UPDATE tests AS t1 JOIN tests AS t2 USING (test_name)
SET t1.unit = t2.unit
WHERE t1.unit IS NULL AND t2.unit IS NOT NULL;
```